# Decide about convergence of the series for $a>0$ and $q\in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

My series is: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty } \frac{q^{n}n^{2}cos( \frac{n\pi}{5} )}{ \frac{n^{3}}{1444}+1001n^{2}+1444an }$$

for $q \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a > 1$.

I did this task for $|q|<1$ and $|q|>1$ using the Cauchy criterion and for $q=-1$ using the Leibnitz criterion. However I cannot do this task for $q=1$. My idea is to use Raabe test but there are big number and it is difficult to use it so I think exist easier way.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it converges using the Dirichlet Test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

When $q=1$ this sum will be less than
$$1444\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos{(\frac{n\pi}{5})}}{n}$$

$|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos{(\frac{n\pi}{5})}| \le 10$ for every integer $N$, this is easy to see because the sum repeats every $20$, and the sum at $20$ is $0$ (Note I choose $10$ randomly, you could get a way better bound if you wanted). And $\frac1n$ is decreasing and goes to 0, so the sum converges.

Comment: There are few unfortunate $a$s, which vanish the denominator.

Comment: @user58697 The problem states that $a>1$ so the denominator will always be positive.

Comment: @ErikParkinson I checked this sum in Wolfram and I got that SumConvergence is for: "Abs[q] <= 1 && q != 1", so Wolfram think that for q=1, the series is divergent. Are you sure of your answer? Because I do not see an error in your reasoning, and yet Wolfram gives something else

Comment: @MP3129 I'm pretty sure, although I could be missing something. Do you know how Wolfram determines convergence? My guess is that it is doing something numerical and ends up guessing incorrectly that it diverges.

Comment: @ErikParkinson Unfortunately Wolfram must be right, because I am writing this series for q=1 and for several different $a$ - for example for 1,2 and really big $a$ to give Wolfram constant values and all the time I get that the series is divergent . Moreover I checked Sum for {n,1,100},{n,1,1000},{n,1,100000} and the sum is constantly growing so this series must be divergent

Comment: @MP3129 Are you sure you plugged it in write? I calculated some partial sums are they were tiny. I'm quite sure it will converge. Also, just because the sum is constantly growing does not necessarily mean it will diverge.

Comment: @ErikParkinson Yes, I am sure. I wonder now whether it matters not that you are showing from the Dirichlet Test that $1444\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos{(\frac{n\pi}{5})}}{n}$ is convergent and then you use Direct comparison test ( if I undestrand correctly), but this test is for $0\le a_{n} \le b_{n}$ for enought big $n$ and in this task $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ do  not meet this condition, because $cos$ is periodic function and can have negative value